# Optimising hql for better performance

Tags: postgresql, grails, hql

I came across some legacy hql. This query is taking around 150 ms . As you can see the code is quite complex and almost unreadable not to mention the performance issue.

```
select distinct pub.id, ret.sector.id, ret.poiSector.id, ret.id, man.id, 0
            from Publisher pub
             left join pub.retailer ret
             left join pub.manufacturer man
            where (
                pub.id in (
                   select publisher_id from Store AS s
                    where s.lat >= 52.297382 and s.lat <= 52.746616 and s.lng >= 13.047624 and s.lng <= 13.785276
                  group by 1
                   having min( sqrt( pow(111.3*(s.lat - 52.522), 2) + pow(67.7*(s.lng - 13.416), 2) ) ) is null or min( sqrt( pow(111.3*(s.lat - 52.522), 2) + pow(67.7*(s.lng - 13.416), 2) ) ) < 25
                )
                or
                (man is not null)
              )
             and (ret is null or ret.hidden is false)
            group by 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
```

I am planning to break up the code segments as well as trying to modify this to increase performance . My question is how can I break this in an efficient way ? will this help in some way ? I dont have full visibility of the system so this are the information I can give you for now .

Comment: `left join pub.retailer ret` desparately needs an `ON...` clause. (Same for manufacturer)

Comment: its HQL hibernate its shorter from this works with hql .

Comment: Your group by clauses make no sense, as there is no aggregate function (like avg, sum, count, etc.) being used in the select clauses. Other than that, you need to optimize the underlying SQL query, by analyzing the execution plan, adding indices, etc.

Comment: its legacy code so it does not make sense to me also :( @JBNizet